# MSAccess: select N records from each category

Tags: sql, ms-access

I can't solve this on MS Access SQL.

I have a **foo** table with this fields:
id, title, category, date

I need to show 6 records showing the 2 most recent items from each category

For example, I have:

```
ID   TITLE   CAT   DATE
------------------------
1    aaa     cat1  12/03/12  
2    sdfs    cat2  12/03/12  
3    asg     cat2  13/03/12  
4    flkgjfl cat3  11/03/12  
5    dgdg    cat1  18/03/12  
6    dfgd    cat1  15/03/12  
7    dgdgd   cat3  18/03/12  
8    dfgd    cat3  12/03/12  
9    uiuou   cat1  14/03/12  
10   ghj     cat4  11/03/12
```

So, I need something like:

```
ID      TITLE   CAT     DATE
----------------------------------
5   dgdg    cat1    18/03/2012  
6   dfgd    cat1    15/03/2012  
3   asg cat2    13/03/2012  
2   sdfs    cat2    12/03/2012  
7   dgdgd   cat3    18/03/2012  
8   dfgd    cat3    12/03/2012
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, `cat` is the name of the table.

```
SELECT cat.ID, cat.TITLE, cat.CAT, cat.DATE
FROM cat
WHERE cat.ID In (
   SELECT TOP 2 id 
   FROM cat c
   WHERE cat.cat = c.cat  
   ORDER BY [date] DESC,id)
ORDER BY cat.CAT, cat.DATE;
```

Comment: @Thanks for the vote. I did rollback because an interesting quirk of Access is that you can use a reserved word without square brackets as long as you prefix it with a table or alias. It is a point I am trying to get across in a small way in a post here and there :)

Comment: Works exactly as I imagined. Frustrating that I could'nt work it out. Thank you very much!